# Under development app installation downgraded by GooglePlay

Tags: android

Short question:
I'm developing a new version for an already published apk. For testing purpose, I installed the dev version on my phone. I observed that my dev app version (which is higher with respect to the already published version) is automatically downgraded by googleplay and I got the published version.

The question is:
How is supposed to manage the under development app in order to avoid the google play downgrade (so the installation of the released version)?

Kind regards,
Vlad

Comment: you can always use beta testing features. provided by google play

Answer (score 0):

Just sing your 'debug' app using the other certificate. The Android device will not update your app if the certificate is different.

Comment: sorry but its sign*

Comment: I use the same certificate for both (released one and dev one). I have to use a real certificate because I use some Google authentication which won't work with a different certificate.

Comment: you can set google auth for two or more certs. Just setup it in google developer console.